# Spring OAuth2 Client - authorization code exchange fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2client

Suppose we have a confidential *OAuth2 Client* performing authorization against the *Authorization Server* using *authorization code* grant type.

Here's a minimal reproducible example.

Client application is running on port `7070`, authorization server on `8080`.

Client configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientsConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistration mainWebClient() {
        
        return ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("main-client")
            .clientId("test_web_client")
            .clientName("test_web_client")
            .clientSecret("secret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .authorizationUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize")
            .tokenUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token")
            .redirectUri("http://localhost:7070/login/oauth2/code/main-client")
            .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(
            mainWebClient()
        );
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oauth2AuthorizedClientManager(
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        
        var clientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository(),
                authorizedClientRepository
            );
        
        clientManager
            .setAuthorizedClientProvider(
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .authorizationCode()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .build()
            );
        
        return clientManager;
    }
}
```

`SecurityFilterChain` - configured login page and for simplicity every request is permitted (`OAuth2AuthorizedClient` client injected in controller as a method argument would trigger the authorization flow):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.oauth2Client(withDefaults())
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/main-client")
            );
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                authorize.anyRequest().permitAll()
            );
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Simplistic controller with `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` injected:

```
@RestController
public class TokenController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getToken(
        @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("main-client")
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client) {
        
        return "access token: " +
            client.getAccessToken().getTokenType() + " " +
            client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

It's important to emphasize that the **problem is rooted in the client's configuration**.

Authorization server does its job **flawlessly** issuing codes and tokens (specifically for the client shown above, server behavior was verified using browser to obtain authorization code and Postman to exchange the code for an access token).

For some reason, the client application is not capable to complete the authorization flow. It receives an authorization code from the authorization server but fails to exchange it.

Here's what happens. Firstly, as expected, the unauthorized request gets redirected to the authorization server running on port 8080.

[image: Redirect to Authorization server]

User credentials provided to the server, and it responds with the authorization code, after receiving the code authorization attempt fails and client application perform the second redirect to the authorization server.

[image: Authorization attempt fails, second redirect]

In the client's logs I found that an `OAuth2AuthenticationException` with the error-code `authorization_request_not_found` occurred in the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` while invoking `attemptAuthentication()` method.

Here are log-messages starting from the point when authorization code was received:

> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.268+03:00 DEBUG 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login/oauth2/code/main-client?code=Dpv-xhYJZcdp4T6B3VoRQZ1UzXR7w9SR2rWYiEUUO5XtGWwJvzxV-WqR2hVwG5Sc1OmsciBkGau65d4Lf7RX5YIoTseudmI6qJbdsBMM7dN2iHnDwXLnsSCAu0WhbS6_&state=EKLnVsMKTT6jx4RrBn3wCbJ-a7mT0ee4xHwgAmEPI5o%3D
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.269+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (8/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.270+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter (9/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.271+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request
>
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found]
> at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
>
> *** few lines omitted ***
>
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.272+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.272+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Handling authentication failure
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.272+03:00 DEBUG 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /oauth2/authorization/main-client?error
>
> *** few lines omitted ***
>
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.304+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (7/15)
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.305+03:00 DEBUG 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-4] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=test_web_client&scope=openid&state=norrUwgtNOpX4olrhN7-nPyVoBhmGYWSU5NJppnjxGA%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:7070/login/oauth2/code/main-client&nonce=6fiTfM0ul1ASzKKf581SUvy092AN4Jq1Vg_a97FMMqs
> 2023-06-15T22:28:23.305+03:00 TRACE 7732 --- [nio-7070-exec-4] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]

Can you please give me hint how can it be fixed?

#### Note

To verify the behavior I've described, **any** sort of OAuth2 authorization server can be used.

Just for the sake of completeness, here's a minimal configuration of the Spring OAuth2 **Authorization Server** which is aware of the client shown previously.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Order(1)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain authSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .authorizationEndpoint(endPoint -> endPoint
                .authenticationProviders(LocalhostCompliantValidator::apply)
            )
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        
        http.exceptionHandling(c ->
            c.authenticationEntryPoint(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")
            )
        );
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Order(2)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain appSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        var user = User.withUsername("user")
            .password("password")
            .authorities("read", "write")
            .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
    
    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient mainClient = RegisteredClient.withId("1")
            .clientId("test_web_client")
            .clientSecret("secret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .redirectUri("http://localhost:7070/login/oauth2/code/main-client")
            .tokenSettings(
                TokenSettings.builder()
                    .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE)
                    .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(24))
                    .build()
            )
            .clientSettings(
                ClientSettings.builder()
                    .requireProofKey(false)
                    .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                    .build()
            )
            .build();
        
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(mainClient);
    }
}
```

Using `localhost` as a redirect URI is against specification and therefore in order to work with the client on `localhost:7070` requires implementing a custom validator, which might look like this:

```
public class LocalhostCompliantValidator implements Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationContext> {
    public static void apply(List<AuthenticationProvider> providers) {
        
        for (var provider: providers) {
            if (provider instanceof OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider oauth2Provider) {
                oauth2Provider.setAuthenticationValidator(new LocalhostCompliantValidator());
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void accept(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationContext context) {
        
        var token = getAuthenticationToken(context);
        
        boolean clientHasRequestedUri = getRegisteredUris(context)
            .contains(token.getRedirectUri());
        
        if (!clientHasRequestedUri) {
            throwAuthenticationException(token);
        }
    }
    
    private static Set<String> getRegisteredUris(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationContext context) {
        return context
            .getRegisteredClient()
            .getRedirectUris();
    }
    
    private static OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationContext context) {
        
        return context.getAuthentication();
    }
    
    private static void throwAuthenticationException(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken token) {
        throw new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationException(
            new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_REQUEST), token
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is usually because of cookie overwriting, see:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5946

Add a line to hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 auth-server
```

And then change "localhost:8080" to "auth-server:8080" in ClientsConfig.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have all routes requiring an authenticated user in an OAuth2 client using authorization code flow: in your case (which is following the default Spring Boot convention) `/login/**` and `/oauth2/**` are accessed during the user authentication process, which means before the user is authenticated.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.oauth2Client(withDefaults())
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login ->
                oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/main-client")
            );
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/login/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But this requires to meet the requirements when providing a `loginPage` (providing with a `@Controller` for it, to start with).

Provided that you have `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` in the classpath and Spring Boot OAuth2 client properties in `application.properties` (or yaml), it seems that this would be just fine:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

I suggest you have a look at [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) for your clients (and resource servers) configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree, permitting access to these paths makes sense, but there's something else that is broken - behavior remains unchanged. While executing the code in the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` the same [condition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/7e0fcb7daeb19543e90aa0375308b4bd67f70b94/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java#L171) gets triggered because `authorizationRequest` appear to be `null` and exception gets thrown.

Comment: You probably haven't provided what is required when [opting out the default login page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-login-page)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment (or update the answer), I didn't get what exactly is missing. Reference documentation says that it's mandatory to configure login page with `oauth2Login().loginPage()`, which is done, and actual redirect is consistent with this configuration: `target-page` -> `localhost:7070/oauth2/authorization/main-clien (i.e. login page)` -> `authorization-server`. What else regarding the login page should be specified?

Comment: You didn't read it. It doesn't say that it is mandatory to configure login Page. It says that if you do so, you have more to configure.

Comment: I meant mandatory for overriding the login page. Forgive me, but I don't see what do you mean by saying "more to configure". Documentation states that the redirection endpoint needs to be configured if the base URI differs from default `/login/oauth2/code/*`, but in this case the client uses default. I don't know how to explain `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` associated with the session is not present in the request repository and what is lacking in my configuration. I'll be glad if you point out the cause.

Comment: I also found that this [sample configuration](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/02d521a4835d8fd93c7efc0aabd5f289aff76139/samples/messages-client/src/main/java/sample/config/SecurityConfig.java#L42) of the client which uses authorization code grant provided by Joe Grandja and Steve Riesenberg has nothing extra added, it's pretty much like my initial one posted in the question.

Comment: from the exact paragraph I linked in the doc __To override the default login page, configure oauth2Login().loginPage() and (optionally) oauth2Login().authorizationEndpoint().baseUri()__ and just after the code sample, a big red warning __You need to provide a @Controller with a @RequestMapping("/login/oauth2") that is capable of rendering the custom login page.__

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76706154/22120450) provided by *Will Phi* is correct.

Browsers map cookies to the **host** (port is not taken into account), therefore after redirect to `localhost:8080` JSESSIONID cookie gets overwritten and the client is not able to recognize it.

As *Will Phi* has pointed out, to resolve the problem we can set an alias to `127.0.0.1` in the `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` - Linux, `Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` - Windows).

There's another solution, instead we can simply use paths starting with `127.0.0.1:7070` for client and paths starting with `localhost:8080` for authorization server. I.e. client registration would look like that:

```
@Bean
public ClientRegistration mainWebClient() {

    return ClientRegistration
        .withRegistrationId("main-client")
        .clientId("test_web_client")
        .clientName("test_web_client")
        .clientSecret("secret")
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
        .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
        .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:7070/login/oauth2/code/main-client")
        .authorizationUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize")
        .tokenUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token")
        .build();
}
```

And `127.0.0.1:7070` also should be used in the redirect URI in client-configuration of the authorization server.